# Are there any Java APIs for for planning or say creating time table

Tags: java, task, schedule, timetable

Some time back, while Googling, I found a Java API (as I remember it was an Apache project but I am not sure) for  creating timetables. By time table 
I mean simple timetable used in schools and colleges

Unfortunately I didn't take note of that API and now I cannot find it.

Please tell me if you know any such open source API available in Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in scheduler in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Apart from that, you can use Quartz, the best one.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Sorry I think my queston was not clear enough. Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

For scheduling tasks you can you built-in timer in Java

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Sorry I think my queston was not clear enough. Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at **Quartz** which is probably the most famous library concerning this topic: [Quartz Library](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

There is also the option to use the superb **Google Guava** library: [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Concerning your edit: I do not have any experience with these libraries but this is the result of my search:

- [Mindfusion JPlanner](http://www.mindfusion.eu/jplanner.html)
- [Resource Scheduler](https://code.google.com/p/resource-schedule/)

Both libraries look really promising although you would need to get a license for the first one.

Comment: Sorry I think my queston was not clear enough. Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to calendar based scheduling, then there is Bedework: https://www.apereo.org/projects/bedework

Its Apache licensed.